# Right way to enable requests with method DELETE in nginx

Tags: rest, nginx

I was writing a RESTful applicaiton in PHP and enabled DELETE, PUT requests for nginx.

```
    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        dav_methods PUT DELETE;
    }
```

When I executed a REST Request with method DELETE, which I wanted to handle inside my index.php - nginx removed the html folder.

What is the right way to tell nginx to pass DELETE requests to my index.php ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NginX executes those HTTP methods (DELETE, PUT) directly without even invoking PHP engine because they are handled by the DAV extension inside nginX.
To overcome the issue, you may use POST HTTP method for all of your API calls, but add additional custom header to indicate the actual REST method - instead of this

```
PUT /api/Person/4 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:10320
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

you will invoke this

```
POST /api/Person/4 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:10320
Content-Type: application/json
X-REST-Method: PUT
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

and then in PHP you will check in this way

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REST_METHOD']!='')
switch($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REST_METHOD'])
{
  case 'PUT':
    ...
    break;
  case 'PATCH':
    ...
    break;
  case 'DELETE':
    ...
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Nginx does not disable PUT or DELETE requests, but it does not allow these requests on a folder index. There isn't really anything that needs to be enabled with nginx (you should remove the dav_methods line), but you need to avoid accessing your index.php through the index directive like:

```
index  index.php index.html index.htm;
```

Instead use try_files to match the index.php file ie like:

```
try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
```

In this case nginx wont complain about your DELETE method.

Comment: `try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;` where should i use this ?