# Laravel resource route on delete shows 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, angularjs, routes, laravel-8

My delete button

```
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" type="button" ng-click="removeSaleTemp(newsaletemp.id)">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </button>
```

My Route

```
Route::resource('api/saletemp', 'SaleTempApiController');
```

When I click on Delete button, it works on my localhost, but when on any hosting. it gives me error

[image]

My Delete Method

```
 $scope.removeSaleTemp = function(id) {
        $http.delete(site_url+'/api/saletemp/' + id).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $http.get(site_url+'/api/saletemp').success(function(data) {
                    $scope.saletemp = data;
                    });
            });
    }
```

I don't know why this is happening on Hosting but works on my localhost.

How can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: It can happen when you click the button twice by mistake, is the resource actually deleted or not ? perhaps you have two requests, one that pass, and the other one that gets a 403

Comment: No i click on button only one time.  But on inspecting in network tab it shows 403 forbidden error. and

Comment: Have you checked your .htaccess? PUT and DELETE headers are allowed in your root folder's .htaccess?

Comment: @MuhammadAnas How can i allow PUT and DELETE headers ?

Comment: @HamzaZafeer what you are using? apache or nginx?

Comment: `<Limit GET POST PUT DELETE>
          Allow from all
    </Limit>`

Comment: @MuhammadAnas nginx

Comment: @MuhammadAnas `<Limit GET POST PUT DELETE>           Allow from all     </Limit>` where i have to add this ?

Comment: oh you're using nginx, .htaccess files are not for nginx. you have to all methods in nginx.conf. you can see following links
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41078890/4264103

Comment: @MuhammadAnas i have checked this answer, but still i am unable to know that how can i add additional header in request in angular and laravel.